# I am having trouble with converting a day with date

Tags: c#

heres what I have so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Month Day Year:");
        ReadMonthDayYear(out int month, out int day, out int year);
        GetDayNum(month, day, year);
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ReadMonthDayYear(out int month, out int day, out int year)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out month);
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day);
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year);
    }

    static int GetDayNum(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            days_in_feb = 29;
        }
        switch (month)
        {
            
            case 2:
                day += 31;
                break;
            case 3:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb;
                break;
            case 4:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31;
                break;
            case 5:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30;
                break;
            case 6:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31;
                break;
            case 7:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30;
                break;
            case 8:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31;
                break;
            case 9:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31;
                break;
            case 10:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30;
                break;
            case 11:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31;
                break;
            case 12:
                day += 31 + days_in_feb + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30;
                break;
                
        }
        return 0;
```

I am trying to get a switch statement to add amount of days to the month. For example Feb 1 = 32 days

I tried to program it with a switch function and get no return.

This question is for class tomorrow and the solution that I tried didn't calculate at all

Comment: You have `return 0` at the end of the function, and in any case you are doing nothing with the result of the function. You probably want `return day;` and then in `Main()` you want `Console.WriteLine(GetDayNum(....).ToString());`

Comment: Why would you do this: `if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))`?
Just use the following: `if (year % 4 == 0)`.

Comment: be patient to new users please!!

Comment: @Toni, look up leap year rules, the OP has it right. When I do this, I use an array where the elements are numberOfDaysInMonth. You calculate Feb's days. Build the array, get the month number and the loop to month number, summing the days. Calculate to the start of the month and add in the dayNum.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace that entire method with [`DateTime.DayOfYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofyear?view=net-5.0)

> Gets the day of the year represented by this instance.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The `DayOfYear` property takes leap years into account when it
> calculates the day of the year. The property value always reflects the
> day of the year in the Gregorian calendar, regardless of the current
> thread culture's current calendar. To retrieve the day of the year in
> a different calendar, call the `Calendar.GetDayOfYear` method of that
> calendar.

**Example**

```
private int GetDayNum(int month, int day, int year)
   => new DateTime(year, month, day).DayOfYear;
```

**Test**

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2021, 2, 1).DayOfYear);
```

**Output**

```
32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (sorry it's on my phone,, not debugged). Make sure to test it well

```
var daysInMonths = new [] {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30};
if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)){
    daysInMonths[1]++; //leap years
}
var daysGoneBy =0;
for (var i =0; i < month-1; ++i) {
    daysGoneBy += daysInMonths[i];
 }
 return daysGoneBy + day;
```

You can use `DateTime.DayOfYear` to write your unit tests.